# Try to find were the data on the info side in Excel is located

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a custom properties in **File** > **Info** > **Properties** > **Custom** and called it **Procent**. It later shows up in the info screen in Excel (**File** > **Info**). See picture:

[image]

The **Procent** on the info screen never changes even if the value of the custom properties has. I have tried to take it away in the custom properties, but it's still there in the info screen.

Were can I find the data stored to the info screen so I can change it with VBA? We use it to show in SharePoint how much we have done in that particular file.

/Joakim

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.CustomDocumentProperties` property *(sounds kinda silly I know...)*

For example, we can iterate through all the individual custom property names and values like so, creating an ordered indexed list of all the custom properties:

```
Private Sub print_properties()
    Dim index As Integer
    index = 1

    For Each property In ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties
      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(index, 1) = property.Name
      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(index, 2) = property.Value
      index = index + 1
    Next property

End Sub
```

I created two custom properties as an example. After launching the procedure I got the following result:

[image]

So now I would know which property has which ID.
In this case, Procent would be 2.

---

> So to answer  your question, briefly, you can reference the value of
>   your procent the following way **`ThisWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties(2).Value`**
>
> *(change 2 to whatever is your Procent property ID)*: